# Merge remote repository commits to the local

Tags: linux, git, merge, repository, poppler

I have two remotes repositories with **C++ Poppler** library, say `A (original-poppler)` and `B (another-poppler)`. The main meaning of second `B` repository is maintaining **Poppler** library for some Linux distro and building for them rpm packages.

`B` was created from `A` just by copying files - I see the first commit  `Ported latest version` and many committed files - it should be from some `A` commit (version `0.20`).

Starting from this `"Ported latest version"` repository `B` lives his life - are added some patches, updated spec files, etc.

`A` repository was updated to the version `0.23.1 (release)` + some other commits after that.
I can clone both repositories and push changes to the `B`.

**How can I update this `B` repository up to the `0.23.1` exactly version (without non-released commits) with respect for `B` changes (patches)**?

Give me please the best maintainable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a branch "releaseA" tracking the release branch in A
2. Make a branch "releaseB" tracking the release branch in B
3. Update both branches by pulling from each repository.
4. Checkout "releaseB"
5. Merge "releaseA" into "releaseB"
6. Push to B.