# Catch up local git repository to remote repository

Tags: git, synchronization, repository, updates

I like to reset my local repository to catch up with the remote repository HEAD. From [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/how-to-reset-my-local-repository-to-be-just-like-the-remote-repository-head) and other sites, I can see the normal command set is:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

However, that's still not enough for me. What else can I check/should I do?

Long story, similar with [Merge remote repository commits to the local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920406/merge-remote-repository-commits-to-the-local), I have two local repositories say `A` and `B`. `B` was created from `A` just by copying files, well in fact, both `A` and `B` are in VM and the VM for `B` was duplicated from `A`. Both repositories `A` and `B` have the same remote git repository.

The repository `B` lives his life - are added some patches, updated spec files, etc, while repository `A` stays at the point of VM duplication. Now I want to bring my local repository `A` up to where `B` is, via their common remote git repository. So I tried `git pull` first, but get `Already up-to-date.`. Then I did the above two commands, i.e.,

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 49e7629 - ...
```

at repository `A`. However, that `49e7629` HEAD is still old, comparing to repository `B`.

The `git log` shows that repository `B` still have more updated than repository `A`. What else can I check/should I do?

Has it anything to do with how my remote git repository is configured? Here is my remote git repository:

```
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myid/myrepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Thanks

Comment: Were the changes in repo B pushed to the remote so that they can be pulled?

Comment: Duh! THAT'S IT. I feel really stupid. :-) Please "answer" so I can "accept". THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in Repo B need to be pushed to the shared remote in order for Repo A to pull them.  Otherwise the changes in B are local only to B.

Comment: Duh! I was so focused on the `nothing added to commit` from the `git status` output, that I completely blindside to the fact `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is :
A and B are clones of the same distant remote repository (named origin)
You want to update A with B changes

A solution for that case would be:
Place yourself in A and then, add B as a remote:

```
git remote add originB /path/to/B/repository
```

You can now list your remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

Which should print:

```
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myid/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myid/myrepo.git (push)
originB /path/to/B/repository (fetch)
originB /path/to/B/repository (fetch)
```

Now you can fetch/merge/... from originB, following the right syntax. For an example:

```
git pull originB anybranch
```

You will find more infos at http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes